# C convex set and D is such that $C\subset D \subset \overline{C} $ then D is path connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let E be a real normed vector space and $C \subset E$

If  C convex set and D is such that $C\subset D \subset \overline{C} $ then D is path connected.

I could prove this if the interior of C is not empty (I take $x$ and $y$ in $D$ and $c$ in $Int(C)$ then I just link $x$ and $y$ with the segments $[x,c]$ and $[c,y]$) but no such hypothesis is made.

Comment: You can show $\overline{C}$ is also convex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $d\in D$, and as it is in $\overline{C}$, find a sequence of points $c_1,c_2,c_3\ldots$ in $C$ that converges to $d$. Now, create a “polygonal line” $c_1c_2c_3\ldots$ (in fact, a map that maps $[0,1/2]$ to $[c_1,c_2]$, $[1/2,3/4]$ to $[c_2,c_3]$ etc., generally mapping smaller and smaller portions of $[0,1]$ to the segments $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$ - and map $1$ to $d$). This map belongs wholly to $C$, except for possibly the last point $d$, so we have managed to connect $d$ (within $D$) with a point ($c_1$) in $C$.

The rest is now trivial as you can repeat the same construction twice to connect two elements of $D$ with two elements of $C$ - and then you just join those two elements of $C$ via a segment to make up a full path, contained in $D$, between those two elements of $ D$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in C$, $b\in D$. We need to connect $a,b$ by a path. If $b\in C$, we use that $C$ is convex, hence path connected.

If $b\not\in C$, then it is in $\bar C$, so it is a limit of a sequence $a_0,a_1,...$ of elements of $C$ where $a_0=a$. Since $C$ is convex, for every $i=0,1,...$ we can connect $a_i$ with $a_{i+1}$ by a path $p_i$ in $C$ (in fact, a line). Then the union of all $p_i$ is a path in $D$ connecting $a$ and $b$.